# Where can I find data on bilateral trade?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, data-request

Where can I find data on bilateral trade between countries in the world over time?
I heard that only International Trade Center has access to this data, but I guess there's a public source. I tried but didn't succeed, for example [this one](http://stat.wto.org/StatisticalProgram/WsdbExportZip.aspx?Language=E).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For aggregated trade, there is a excellent database from CEPII called histtrade. It covers data from the first industrial revolution. The site also has data covering disaggregated  trade but only with limited observations.

http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/bdd_modele/bdd_modele.asp

A second data set is the Barbieri Data set, that can be downloaded from the COW project.

http://www.correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/bilateral-trade